# ASP.NET MVC Router

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have this routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Funcionario",
                "{funcionario}",
                new { controller = "Funcionario", action = "Index", funcionario = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "Route.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Servico",
                "{funcionario}/{servico}",
                new { controller = "Funcionario", action = "Servico", funcionario = UrlParameter.Optional, servico = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "Route.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = @"\d+" }, // Parameter defaults
                new string[] { "Route.Controllers" }
            );            
        }
```

But I can't access my home/index. For example:

**Working**

http://mydomain.com/pablo

http://mydomain.com/pablo/cozinha

http://mydomain.com/home/index/0

**Not Working**

http://mydomain.com/

http://mydomain.com/home/index

Answer (score 0):

All the routes defined are generic.

1. http://mydomain.com/pablo will match the first route
2. http://mydomain.com/pablo/cozinha will match the second route
3. http://mydomain.com/ will match the first route (So home page will not be displayed)
4. http://mydomain.com/home/index will match the second route. (So home page will not be displayed)

Routes should be defined from specific to generic order. e.g. you can change the routes as,

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Servico",
            "Func/{funcionario}/{servico}",
            new { controller = "Funcionario", action = "Servico", funcionario = UrlParameter.Optional, servico = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "Route.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = @"\d+" }, // Parameter defaults
            new string[] { "Route.Controllers" }
        );            
    }
```

So, your requests will be like,

1. http://mydomain.com/Func/pablo
2. http://mydomain.com/Func/pablo/cozinha
3. http://mydomain.com/
4. http://mydomain.com/home/index

So, routes should be declared carefully, so that request will not match any unwanted route

Comment: Ok! this way, passing "/Func" works. But I don't want to use the controller name.

I was thinking in verify when is controoler, action or parameter. Maybe in a BaseController. But I don't know how to do.

Comment: Then you will not be able to differentiate the requests. So requests will not match appropriate route.

Comment: You need some identifier that differentiate the routes. it can be anything, neednot be controller name

Comment: I was thinking...

If when has only one parameter and was a name of controller, I could force to redirect to "mycontroller/index".

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000322/onactionexecuting-causing-inifinte-redirect-for-handling-session-timeout